# Passing certificate from local machine to webapi

Tags: c#, client-certificates

I have created a service which runs on local machine. Local machine have some certificate installed which is used for authorization and hence fetch access token.
All these things are previously taking place on local machine.

```
        GetCertificateFromStore();
        AuthenticationResult result = _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(string ResourceId,ClientAssertionCertificate certificateCredential).Result;
        if (result != null)
        {
            AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

> GetCertificateFromStore() is setting certificateCredential = new ClientAssertionCertificate(ClientId, certificate);

Now I want to pass this certificate to some web api and return access token from there to local machine. I am able to pass certificate, but on web api side, passed certificate showing error of private key not found.

```
// Below is the code I am using to call api for accessing and returning access token

client.PostAsJsonAsync(ApiConfigHelper.getAzureAccessToken, certificateCredential).ContinueWith(task =>
                 {
                     if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                     {
                         var response = task.Result;
                         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                         {
                            // token = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;
                            token = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                         }
                     }
                 });
            upload.Wait();
```

> The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate. is the exception I am getting.

I need to know can I pass certificate to some api to fetch access token.

Thanks 
Subham

Comment: you **MUST NOT** transfer private keys to remote machines over network. You obviously do somethind wrong. How do you generate your token?

Comment: I have mentioned above.I am getting token by using AcquireTokenSync method.
          
Second parameter of this method is coming form    ------------

certificateCredential = new ClientAssertionCertificate(ClientId, certificate);

where two parameters are :


ClientId= "3483fb8d-9e08-4acf-9f26-xxxxxxxxx" 
  CertificateName="CN=xxxxxxxxxx, OU=TestUsers, OU=Test, OU=xxxxxxxxxxx, DC=xxops, DC=com"